# C# best way to compare two time of the day

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I woulld like to know if a specified time of the day is passed. I don't really like the way I am doing:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan _whenTimeIsOver = new TimeSpan(16,25,00);

internal static bool IsTimeOver()
{
    return DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Subtract(_whenTimeIsOver ).Ticks > 0; 
}
```

How do you do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about:

```
internal static bool IsTimeOver()
{
    return DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > _whenTimeIsOver;
}
```

Operator overloading is very helpful for date and time work :) You might also want to consider making it a property instead of a method.

It's a slight pity that there isn't a

```
DateTime.CurrentTime
```

or

```
TimeSpan.CurrentTime
```

to avoid `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` (just as there's `DateTime.Today`) but alas, no...

I have a set of extension methods on `int` in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which would make the initialization of `_whenTimeIsOver` neater - you'd use:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan _whenTimeIsOver = 16.Hours() + 25.Minutes();
```

It's not to everyone's tastes, but I like it...

Comment: Ok thought we cannot compare DateTime and TimeSpan object, I was wrong. I like the initilaisation.

Comment: @Duaner: You're not comparing `DateTime` with `TimeSpan` - you're comparing two `TimeSpans`. The `TimeOfDay` property returns `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 14):

```
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > _whenTimeIsOver)
    ....
```

Comment: I was faster, but my initial answer contained a small error :)